# How to pass a NodeJS parameter to NestJS to extend the stack trace

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I must pass the node parameter `--stack_trace_limit=200` to NestJS to show an extended trace. I want to continue using nest-cli for development reasons. It seems that NestJS does not proxify NodeJS parameters to NodeJS.

Regards.

Comment: It's `--stack-trace-limit`, not `--stack_trace_limit`. If you are trying something and it doesn't work, check if it works with the first variant; maybe,  that's the real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use [`NODE_OPTIONS`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_optionsoptions) variable, NodeJS's runtime will pick it up.

For example:

```bash
NODE_OPTIONS="--stack_trace_limit=200" nest start
```

Answer (score 2):

another way is by using the `--exec` option from Nest's CLI:

```
nest start --exec "node --stack_trace_limit=200"
```